# JavaScript - How do I stop a script from running onClick()?

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, gallery

I'm just trying to figure out how to stop the script from running and rotating images onClick().

Any help? Please?

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('#imageGallery').addEventListener('click', function () {
    clearTimeout(thetimer);
});
```

This will only *stop* the images.  If you want to be able to toggle stopping and animating, you can keep track of the stop/resume state using `dataset` (at least, I suggest you do it that way) and call `numb` when resuming state to start the timeout once again.

This is not 100% cross-browser compatible.  You'll have to use `attachEvent` for IE, and you shouldn't use `thetimer` as a global variable, but declare it with `var`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! How would I incorporate this document.querySelector into my code? I'm a bit confused. I just tried putting it into my .JS file but it's not doing anything when I click on the image. (Meaning, it's not stopping the script.) Oh, and I don't need to restart it once it's stopped.

Comment: @Virgil If you post your full JS code somewhere (or link to your website or create an example on jsfiddle.net) I can do the tweaking that you may need.

Comment: You can do it with a name if you really want to, but it's easier to use an ID: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/pGzA6/5/